# PowerCLI deploy template

Tags: powercli

I am trying to deploy an OVA file using PowerCLI on my laptop. The script works if the -Source is on a UNC share or in this case $ovfpath is a mapped drive on my laptop. But what this does is drag the 12gb ova file across the network every time a new vm gets created. What I would like is to have the -Source on the datastore and only have to copy it across the WAN 1 time. I've tried using https:\host.... but the script fails. If I use the vSphere GUI to deploy from template and use the HTTPS url it works. Any ideas for how to access the -Source from a datastore?

```
$ovfpath = Get-ChildItem z:\

$myDatastore = Get-Datastore -Name "Datastore2"
$vmHost = Get-VMHost -Name "$newHost"
$vmHost | Import-vApp **-Source "$ovfpath\Win2012_R2_Std.ova"** -Name newVM01 -Datastore $myDatastore -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

can you not import the OVF, convert the imported VM to a template and then deploy additional VMs from the template?
That way it will not use the network each time.